# How to retrieve the data from XML into CSS

Tags: xml

I have a requirement like I have to place the path of an image in an xml file and should retrieve from the css file. SO that I change the image without touching the code.Is it possible? If yes what is the to do this?

Answer (score 1):

We would all wish it were that easy. :)

1. To read from the XML file you will need a scripting language such as [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php)
2. From PHP or other scripting language you will need to show the result in an [HTML](http://www.html.net/tutorials/html/lesson2.php) page.
3. And finally use [CSS](http://www.whatiscss.com/) if needed, to format the HTML page design as the end user will see it

Comment: You can also parse XML with javascript in the browser.